# Error adding a json object in a json localstorage

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I'm trying to add a json in other json object, stored in local storage but I get an error ¨: Object # has no method 'push'

The local storage object is:

```
shops {
        "c": [
            {
                "cliente_id": "12",
                "cliente_name": "Vermut",
                "cliente_url": "vermut",
                "categoria_name": "Restaurantes",
                "imagen": "1364.jpg",
                "telefono": "456987123",
                "descripcion": "El mejor sitio en el centro",
                "latitud": "41.3865749",
                "longitud": "2.1745545999999",
                "direccion": "Carrera",
                "porcentaje": "50",
                "distancia": "0.0764"
            },
            {
                "cliente_id": "92",
                "cliente_name": "mexicano",
                "cliente_url": "mexicano",
                "categoria_name": "Restaurantes",
                "imagen": "135.jpg",
                "telefono": "",
                "descripcion": "Comida a\r\n\r\nNuestros . \r\n",
                "latitud": "3.9999",
                "longitud": "6.9999",
                "direccion": "Mexicana",
                "porcentaje": "50",
                "distancia": "0.771095"
            }
        ]
    }
```

And this is the code with which I try to place the json inside the other one. What I'm doing wrong?

```
    function addItem() {
    //I retrieve the old object
        var oldCli = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shops')) || [];  
        var newCli = {
        "c": [
            {
                "cliente_id": "1",
                "cliente_name": "Restaurante Quebracho",
                "cliente_url": "restaurante-quebracho",
                "categoria_name": "Restaurantes",
                "imagen": "1355.jpg",
                "telefono": "123654469",
                "descripcion": "Quebrachos",
                "latitud": "5.3456",
                "longitud": "2.1264",
                "direccion": "Ronda Quebracho",
                "porcentaje": "25",
                "distancia": "0.4273"
            },
            {
                "cliente_id": "2",
                "cliente_name": "Malinche",
                "cliente_url": "disco-malinche",
                "categoria_name": "Discotecas",
                "imagen": "13493.png",
                "telefono": "234567",
                "descripcion": "Malinches.",
                "latitud": "6.98765",
                "longitud": "1.23456",
                "direccion": "C Malinche 42",
                "porcentaje": "30",
                "distancia": "1.0994"
            }
        ]
    };

        oldCli.push(newCli);

        localStorage.setItem('shops', JSON.stringify(oldCli));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call `push` on the `shops` object not on the `c` array, you could do:

```
var oldCli = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shops')).c || [];
```

Comment: Hi Alberto, and thanks again. What I'm trying this time is save th 2 json inside the other one like:___________________________________  {
    "c": [
        {
            "cliente_id": "1",
            "cliente_name": "Quebracho 1",
        },
        {
            "cliente_id": "2",
            "cliente_name": "Malinche 1"
        }
    ]
    "c": [
        {
            "cliente_id": "1",
            "cliente_name": "Quebracho 2"
        },
        {
            "cliente_id": "2",
            "cliente_name": "Malinche 2"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Either update your question or create a new one, like this is difficult to understand what you're doing.